# Язык C, typedef неизвестной структуры

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Ситуация следующая:

*file.c:*

```
#include "file.h"

struct s_my_struct
{
    // ...
};
```

*file.h:*

```
// Защита от повторного включения, заголовочники...

typedef struct s_my_struct my_struct;
```

*main.c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    my_struct m;// Так, ясное дело, нельзя.

    my_struct *pm;// Так можно.

    pm = (my_struct*)malloc(sizeof(my_struct));// Так тоже нельзя.

    pm = (my_struct*) &any_object;// Так можно.

    // НО! Мы не можем обращаться к полям структуры при помощи
    // pm->, потому что описание структуры нам неизвестно...
}
```

Вопросы такие:

1. Является ли вообще корректным поведением то, что компилятор даже не дает предупреждения о том, что мы объявляем указатель на тип, который в принципе неизвестен, через его синоним? Или это очередная *дыра* языка?
2. Если это корректно, то для чего такое дело ввели в язык? Как это использовать? Какие полезные вещи становятся возможны благодаря этому?
3. Ну и если это корректно, то в каком месте **Стандарта** искать описание того, что за магию мы делаем, и как она обрабатывается при компиляции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в вопросе описка, пропущено `struct`:

> ```
> typedef struct s_my_struct my_struct;
> ```

Без этого ни один компилятор Си это не соберёт.

> Является ли вообще корректным поведением то, что компилятор даже не дает предупреждения о том, что мы объявляем указатель на тип, который в принципе неизвестен, через его синоним? Или это очередная дыра языка?

Да, это абсолютно корректная вещь. Называется указателем на *неполный тип*, один из базовых объектов языка.

> Если это корректно, то для чего такое дело ввели в язык? Как это использовать? Какие полезные вещи становятся возможны благодаря этому?

Это краеугольный камень инкапсуляции в Си. Сплошь и рядом используется в различных библиотеках. Дабы скрыть от пользователя внутренние структуры отдав ему на откуп одну ручку в виде указателя. Например в том же Gtk, хотя сами типы большинства объектов не являются неполными, они содержат внутри себя указатель на приватные данные `GtkWidgetPrivate` (из *gtk/gtkwidget.h*):

```
struct _GtkWidget
{
  GInitiallyUnowned parent_instance;
  GtkWidgetPrivate *priv;
};
```

Таким образом эти данные пользователю недоступны.

Кроме изоляции грязных рук пользователя от библиотеки это даёт возможность менять внутреннее устройство структуры не вызывая проблем в пользовательском коде и прочие хрестоматийные бонусы инкапсуляции...

Также без неполного типа невозможно сделать перекрёстные структуры c перекрёстными указателями подобного рода:

```
// struct bar;

struct foo { struct bar *bar_p; };
struct bar { struct foo *foo_p; };
```

> Ну и если это корректно, то в каком месте Стандарта искать описание того, что за магию мы делаем, и как она обрабатывается при компиляции?

В главах описывающих что такое *неполный тип* (*incomplete type*) и как работают указатели (6.2.5 и другие). Но прежде чем лезть в стандарт лучше разобраться с этм по какому-нибудь букварю.

Comment: Каюсь, грешен... Спасибо за развернутую помощь.

Comment: По поводу GtkWidget, у меня можно сделать GtkWidget widget; И потом обратиться к полям объекта widget, хотя GtkWidget и является неполным типом-синонимом.

Comment: А если будет такая ситуация: в глобальной области видимости объявлен неполный тип struct s_s; Затем имеется две функции, которые этот неполный тип видят. Каждая функция в своем теле делает этот тип полным, но описывает его по-разному. Это корректно? И если да, то что происходит, и для чего существует такая возможность?

Comment: c gtk пример плохой — в строгом смысле виджеты не являются неполными типами... с другой стороны они содержат указатель типа `_GtkWidgetPrivate`, который таковым уже является...

Comment: По описанной ситуации — это Си... как говорят, здесь ни кто не будет воздерживать тебя от простреливания собственной ноги... короче говоря где-то такой механизм можно применить, например в контейнере для произвольного типа, но с большой вероятностью это причина ошибки и UB.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: о чём именно?..

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

В заголовке объявляется тип и весь его интерфейс:

```
struct opaque;
struct opaque *new(int arg);
int get_value(struct opaque *);
void set_value(struct opaque *, int new_value);
void process(struct opaque *);
void destroy(struct opaque *);
```

Это и есть весь набор операций, которые пользователь может применять к такому типу. Определение типа и сами методы написаны в .c и пользователю неизвестны, все значения и побочные эффекты получаются только от вызова методов. Легкий способ пытаться соблюдать контракты и устроить decoupling в Сях.

Answer (score 1):

1. Указатель, он на то и указатель. Он имеет фиксированный размер, а больше ничего не интересно
2. Вы пишете библиотеку, в которой оперируете некой структурой. Вам нужно ее возвращать пользователю и принимать ее обратно (аналог HWND). Детали структуры вы публиковать не хотите (например, от версии к версии вы ее изменяете). Вы отдаете пользователю указатель на неизвестную структуру. При этом, в отличии от `void *` пользователь еще получает возможность контроля типов при передачи этого указателя как параметра